# Programmatically set dropdownlist selected after being populated with json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="resourceName"></select>
```

I populate the `select` with data from JSON:

```
jQuery.getJSON("/Booking/GetMachine", { 
    TechnologyName: technologyName, 
    EquipmentTypeName: equipmentTypeName 
}, function (machines) {
    var $select = $('#resourceName');
    $('#resourceName').empty(); 
    $.each(machines, function (i, machine) { 
        var option = $('<option>', {
            value: machine.trim()
        }).html(machine.trim()).appendTo($select);
    });
});
```

Once popualated I want to set the selected value of the dropdownlist that matches a variable.

```
jQuery("#resourceName").val(resourceName);
```

However it does not work as intended. I would really appreciate it if someone would check if I've made any mistakes. Thank you guys

Comment: If you set the `val()` of the `select` within the callback function, after the `option` elements have been set, your code should work fine.

Comment: Does the value of `resourceName` match the value of one of the options you added?

Comment: thank you @RoryMcCrossan! Here I was trying to figure out what went wrong after trying the suggestions found. It works like a charm! Thank you for your kind attention :)

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `val()` of the `select` within the callback function, after the `option` elements have been set, your code should work fine:

```
jQuery.getJSON("/Booking/GetMachine", { 
    TechnologyName: technologyName, 
    EquipmentTypeName: equipmentTypeName 
}, function (machines) {
    var $select = $('#resourceName');
    $('#resourceName').empty(); 
    $.each(machines, function (i, machine) { 
        var option = $('<option>', {
            value: machine.trim()
        }).html(machine.trim()).appendTo($select);
    });
    $("#resourceName").val(resourceName); // < set the value here
});
```

This is because the AJAX call is asynchronous. This means that if you try to set the value outside of the callback, you are actually setting the value *before* the request completes which means that there are no `option` elements to choose.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code work

```
    jQuery.getJSON("/Booking/GetMachine", { 
        TechnologyName: technologyName, 
        EquipmentTypeName: equipmentTypeName 
    }, function (machines) {
        var $select = $('#resourceName');
        $('#resourceName').empty(); 
        $.each(machines, function (i, machine) { 
            var option = $('<option>', {
                value: machine.trim()
            }).html(machine.trim()).appendTo($select);
        }).promise().done( function(){      $("#resourceName").val(resourceName);// < set the value here } );

    });
```